# Remove x86 code from universal app

Tags: macos, command-line, apple-silicon, binary, universal-binaries

I'm using macOS 12 on an M1 MBP. There are certain apps that are mostly code and not resource, very large in size, and not needed in Rosetta. Therefore, I wrote a script to remove x86 components from these applications. The script is very slow and the current way of checking that the applications still work is simply to open it, which is not a very comprehensive check. So:

1. Is there any other solutions, tools, or scripts that can perform this faster?
2. Is there a more thorough check I can perform to ensure that the application, after removing the x86 code, still works perfectly, and that I can delete the clone / backup I made before the process?

Script in fish:

```
cd /path/to/application/bundle/
for i in ** ; lipo -extract arm64 $i -o $i.1 ; mv $i.1 $i ; end
```

Comment: There is no reason to do this.  You aren't going to save enough space that it would matter, and may corrupt the signature of the app.

Comment: @Marc Wilson No, it saves around 40% space for mainly-code apps. No, it does not corrupt the signature because there are separate signatures for x86 and ARM codes. I (sort of) know what I'm doing.

Comment: Did you check which part is slow? I assume it's the `lipo` part, something you obviously can't skip. You can parallelize it though, either by writing a smarter loop or using tools like GNU Parallel. But as this is a one-off thing you run only once, speed probably doesn't matter that much.

Comment: I found that someone has also written script to do this: https://github.com/Oct4Pie/archify